# Is there an auto-completion feature when writing if statements?

Tags: if-statement, delphi, settings, brackets

I am developing with Delphi 10.2 Tokyo.

When I try to write a conditional expression with a `()` when entering an `if` statement, it becomes `(true)` when I enter `(` and I have to delete the `true` part before writing the conditional expression.

Can I make it so that it automatically becomes `()` and the cursor is in the middle?

I have been trying to find out if there are any good settings in the tool options. However, I could not find any such settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want will work when you follow the following steps:

1. type `if` in the code editor and press <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>TAB</kbd> to invoke the "if"-code template
2. type in your conditional expression
3. press <kbd>SHIFT + TAB</kbd> to place the cursor at the beginning of the expression
4. type `(` (opening round bracket) and your expression should be enclosed in brackets now
5. press <kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to finish the input for the conditional expression

For further references about live (or code) templates and how to add/edit them please see the official documentation:

1. [Live Templates](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Live_Templates)
2. [Creating Live Templates](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Creating_Live_Templates)

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I did what you said and now I can write if statements without typing Back Space!